# How to Parameterize Linq Query or Lambda Query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I write some Parameterize Lambda Queries

```
        //Method 1:
        Func<SalesOrderLineEntity, bool> func01 = (o => o.SOLNumber == "123456");
        var q01 = _context.SalesOrderLineEntities.Where(func01).ToList();
        //Got the result, but SQLServer Read All Records to memory before "where"

        //Method 2:
        Expression<Func<SalesOrderLineEntity, bool>> exp02 = (o => o.SOLNumber == "123456");
        var q02 = _context.SalesOrderLineEntities.Where(exp02).ToList();
        //Got the result,Exec "Where" in SQLServer

        //Method 3:
        Expression<Func<SalesOrderLineEntity, bool>> exp03 = (o => func01(o));
        var q03 = _context.SalesOrderLineEntities.Where(exp03.Compile()).ToList();
        //Same to Method 1,because Compile() result is Func<SalesOrderLineEntity, bool>

        //Method 4:
        var q04 = _context.SalesOrderLineEntities.Where(exp03).ToList();
        //Error:The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities
```

**Method 1 and 3**：Efficiency is very low
**Method 4**:Error

**Method 2**:Need I Build a Expression through the Lambda. I feel it is very difficult, because i will use many "if,else".it easier to create a function.
What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: you need the Expression variation (without compile), because EF builds the actual SQL query based on the expression tree.

Comment: Very surprised method 1 loads all in memory before where clause, that shouldn't happen unless the property SOLNumber is not a column in the db but rather a custom property (defined in a partial class or something)

Comment: ooooh, it's because there are 2 implementations for Where, one for IEnumerable<> which is used in Method 1 and one for IQueryable which relies on Expression trees -> method 2. I'm right right?

Comment: So you want to be able to do Method 2 with an arbitrary string instead of `"123456"`, is that right?

Comment: @dutzu yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

#### Variations

**Method 1**: EF reads all the records from the DB because you pass a `Func` into the `Where` clause, which is not the right candidate: EF cannot extract the needed information from it to build the query, it can only use that function on an in-memory collection.

**Method 2**: this is the correct way to do EF queries because EF builds up the actual query based on the `Expression tree`. It may look like the same as Method 1 when you write `.Where` but this is different.

[IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) extension methods are using [Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), so you can (or EF can) evaluate that information at runtime.

**Method 3**: this is essentially the same as Method 1, because you compile the expression. This is a key difference while you use them: an expression contains the informations to build the actual operation but that's not the operation itself. You need to compile it before (or for example you can build SQL queries based on them, that's how EF works).

**Method 4**: EF cannot translate your `func01()` call to any SQL function. It cannot translate any kind of code because it needs an equivalent SQL operation. You can try to use a general method, you will get the same result, it's not about the Func.

#### What happens here?

If we simplify the underlying process then the answer above might by more clear.

```
//Method 2:
Expression<Func<SalesOrderLineEntity, bool>> exp02 = (o => o.SOLNumber == "123456");
var q02 = _context.SalesOrderLineEntities.Where(exp02).ToList();
//Got the result,Exec "Where" in SQLServer
```

EF can read the following (via the expressions):

- the user want to filter with `Where`
- here is an expression for that, let's get some information
- well, it needs `SalesOrderLineEntity` and I have a mapping for that type
- the expression tells that the property `SOLNumber` must be equal to "123456"
- ok, I have a mapping for `SOLNumber` so it's good
- and I can translate the equal operator to an equivalent SQL operator
- everything okay, so we can build the SQL query

Of course, you cannot do this with a `Func` for example because that object doesn't contain these informations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable but have you look at compiled queries: [Compiled Queries (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896297(v=vs.100).aspx) which should result in a more efficient SQL statement