# asp.net mvc Filter Database using multi-select list and return this to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created some multi-select lists using html helpers. I have populated the list using the database making sure that each list is distinct. I was wondering how can I make a filter that would allow me to get the users selection list, filter the database and return this data as JSON in order to show on my site?

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3. 
Thanks

Comment: There are 4 distinct parts here: 1. passing your select list parameters back to a controller; 2. extracting appropriate data from the database; 3. returning the data to the page as JSON; 4. displaying the returned data on the page. Which of these are you unsure about?

Comment: Well the main problem is that I want to create a dynamic query. I need to know how I would be able to create a dynamic query where I take in several selected options.

Comment: Why don't you demonstrate how you are populating the list using the database - there are some different ways to do this - and then we can determine the best thing for this approach.

Comment: public ActionResult View()
        {
            using (database ctx = new database)
            {
                var something = ctx.Table.Select(x => x.something).Distinct();
                ViewBag.something = new MultiSelectList(something.ToList());
                return View();
            }
        }

Comment: So your question seems to be: how do you parameterize Entity Framework calls. Something like [How to Parameterize Linq Query or Lamda Query in Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455789/how-to-parameterize-linq-query-or-lamda-query-in-entity-framework) might be of help.